# get the value of bonced object in side the watch properties

Tags: vue.js

```
 data() {
    return {
     subproduct:[{PUHT:100},{PUHT:255},{PUHT:10}]
     }
 }
```

the watch properties that look for change inside the "subproduct" and then if I add a new object to "subproduct" it will store the value of PUHT like this

```
  watch:{
    "fact.subproduct": function(new_product) {
        var totalhtt=0.0;
        totalhtt+= parseFloat( new_product.PUHT);
      }
   }
```

**but didn't work I don't know how to enter that 'PUHT' value from 'new_product' **

Comment: "if I add a new object to "subproduct" - how exactly? With push? What if the array were modified in some other way? Here there's no way to distinguish the way it was modified. Do this in the place where subproduct is modified, there may be no reason to use a watcher

Comment: yes i add it with push like this    this.subproduct.push({
                                                    PUHT: 233,}) on btn click